# How to find whether two variable in list are nearer

Tags: python-3.x

```
array = ['3', 'pnwites', 'it', 'we', 'sy', 'nwjccoor,', '_', 'invoice', '°—', 'page:', '1', 'of', '1', 'nucor', 'steel', 'tuscaloosa,', 'inc.', 'please', 'make', 'checks', 'payable', 'and', 'mail', 'to:', 'invoice', 'date:', '12/29/2021', 'seenivoee]

variable =  ['invoice', 'date:']
```

Is there any solution to get True whether the words 'invoice' and 'date:' closest to each other

Comment: Check if their indexes are +1 or -1 different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find whether the two values in `variables` occur as sublist in `array` (I'm not entirely sure whether that's your question), you could do

```py
pairs = [
    [array[i], array[i+1]]
    for i in range(len(array)-1)
]
is_contained_as_sublist = variable in pairs
```

In fact, you don't even have to build the list of `pairs`, but can use a generator expression:

```py
is_contained_as_sublist = any(
    [array[i], array[i+1]] == variable
    for i in range(len(array)-1)
)
```